# Woocommerce add to cart button style

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce on my site(http://masterscoffeeandwater.com/bottled-water/) and I want to style button "add to cart" on my site ,currently it  is appearing as text link that is very boring ..

I am using below CSS but it's not working

```css
.single_add_to_cart_button:hover {
    background: green !important;
}
.single_add_to_cart_button {
    background: red !important;
}
```

any help would be appreciated

I am stuck here

Answer (score 0):

add your class 'single_add_to_cart_button' to add-to-cart.php (wp-content/themes/YOUR THEME/woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php)

you will find 'anchor' tag there. just add class in that.

Comment: I added but it's not working :(  `echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
 sprintf( '<a class="single_add_to_cart_button" href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
`

Comment: you will find below line in add-to-cart.php (wp-content/themes/YOUR THEME/woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php)                                                                                           $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'YOUR CLASS NAME' : '', ................it will work.

Comment: I tried ,it is not working and also is this path correct wp-content/themes/YOUR THEME/woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php  ,I think add_to_cart is in plugins folder not in themes

Comment: it is also in your theme folder if you want custom woocommerce template for yout theme. send me code of add-to-cart.php.

Comment: I dont' have in theme folder Hardik ,I have add_to_cart in only plugins folder ,here is the link [link] (http://www.filedropper.com/add-to-cart)

Comment: also ,I copied woocommerce directory from plugins folder to my theme folder and location is wp-content/theme/woocommerce/templates/loop/add-to-cart